# missing .h file when creating lexical analyzer

Tags: c, gcc, lex, flex-lexer

I am trying to compile a .l file to create a lexical analyzer. the code is:

```
%{
#include "ifanw.tab.h"
extern int yylval;
%}
%%
"="      { return EQ; }
"!="     { return NE; }
"<"      { return LT; }
"<="     { return LE; }
">"      { return GT; }
">="     { return GE; }
"+"      { return PLUS; }
"-"      { return MINUS; }
"*"      { return MULT; }
"/"      { return DIVIDE; }
")"      { return RPAREN; }
"("      { return LPAREN; }
":="     { return ASSIGN; }
";"      { return SEMICOLON; }
"IF"     { return IF; }
"THEN"   { return THEN; }
"ELSE"   { return ELSE; }
"FI"     { return FI; }
"WHILE"  { return WHILE; }
"DO"     { return DO; }
"OD"     { return OD; }
"PRINT"  { return PRINT; }
[0-9]+   { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
[a-z]    { yylval = yytext[0] - 'a'; return NAME; }   
\        { ; }
\n       { nextline(); }
\t       { ; }
"//".*\n { nextline(); }
.        { yyerror("illegal token"); }
%%
```

the commands I have entered were:

```
flex filename.l 

gcc -c lex.yy.c -o out
```

the output was

```
filename.l:2:23: fatal error: ifanw.tab.h: no such file or directory.
```

Is the problem in gcc libraries? If so, where can I download an updated/fixed library?
Otherwise, what's the problem?

Comment: In the future; be sure to be careful about tagging. Flex is used for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework. Lex and/or gnu-flex are used for the lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc` is telling you what the trouble is: it cannot find the include file you specified.

It's not a problem of libraries.

You need to create that file from your .y file first

```
bison --debug --verbose -d ifanw.y
```

You might find [this small tutorial](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/02/example-using-bison-and-flex-with/) useful.

If you do not have the .y file, then you're trying to compile an incomplete package, and that just won't work. You will have to somehow obtain the missing files from wherever you got the files you already have.

Comment: Oh, that's OK then. Give a look to that tutorial, it will show you what a .y file should look like. If you're a beginner, I'd suggest you first read some theory about grammars in general, and lex/yacc specifically. Otherwise, if you are trying to solve *another* problem with a parser, maybe you'd be better off by asking advice on the problem itself. Someone might then also suggest the most practical grammar approach.

Comment: All the options to bison except -d are superfluous imho.

Comment: Yes @FUZxxl , they are - for the purpose of generating the output. But in case the OP needed some feedback on the .y file itself, they might've come handy.

Comment: @lserni IMHO they just clutter the output of make. I prefer adding such options ad-hoc when I need them to keep the output of make short.

Answer (score 0):

Add the flex library to your gcc command:

```
gcc -c lex.yy.c -lfl -o out
```

Also, if you're including a `tab.h` file, do you have any bison file? If so, are you compiling it with the `bison` command?

By the name that's a bison generated header so you should have a file with the `.y` extension which you need to compile with the bison command: `bison *.y`

And after compiling with `bison`, execute your commands again, but remember to add the flex library flag (`-lfl`).

Comment: this command had same output.I tryed command gcc -lfl and output was'usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfl_pic.a(libfl_pic_a-libmain.o): In function `main':
/build/buildd/flex-2.5.35/libmain.c:30: undefined reference to `yylex'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

'

Comment: Do you have a file named `ifanw.tab.h`?

Comment: By the name that's a bison generated header so you should have a file with `.yy` or `.y` extension which you need to compile with the `bison` command: `bison *.yy *.y`

Comment: what is your mean? i don't know where is gcc libraries.

Comment: That library is installed with the `flex` package. You don't need to know where it is.

Comment: where is the file with .yy or .y extension? i am new to this field

Comment: It is the file where the grammar rules are defined. You are now compiling *one* of the intermediate files that have to be generated from the grammar rules. You either need the grammar file, or *all* of its intermediates, otherwise you can't build the executable.

Comment: @NiceN :/ I can't know man, it's a source file of your project, it's not automatically generated, you need to actually code it (from scratch if it's missing).

Comment: Friend, you're complaining that **your** door isn't opening and the error shown is "No key in the lock". How do you expect someone else to come up with **your** code?